# Retrieve Image from mysql (BLOB) and display them into ListView

Tags: android, mysql, listview

I don't know this is duplicate or not.

But i really need help to show image from mysql and then set it into listview. the left side is image and the right side is text. Both of them were retrieved from mysql.

Please give me some tutorials or maybe the reference link will be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found some websites that can be used to show image from mysql and then set it into listview but some of them might use different libraries. Here are the links:

- [Android Custom Listview With Image And Text](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)
- [ListView Example in Android with data populated from a MySQL database using php.](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/09/23/simplest-lazy-loading-listview-android-data-populated-mysql-database-php/)
- [Custom Listview With Image And Text Using ArrayAdapter](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/)

Hope it helps! Good Luck!